# Using neural networks for multi target prediction

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, neural-networks

I have a spatial dataset with some xs and ys at different spatial locations. I want to learn a non linear regression function using neural networks. I looked in to the training data and the outputs are different locations i.e. ys are high correlated. So I was thinking of modelling a multi target prediction, instead of learning a separate regression for each case. I was thinking of learning a joint one using neural networks. I tried to use `nntool` of Matlab, however it lets me model only one output at a time. What should I do to model multiple outputs at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

`nntool` accepts any number of input and output dimensions. Simply prepare your data in form of matrices, ie. if you want to train neural network for two target logical function $$ f(x,y) = (x \text{ and } y,x \text{ or } y)$$

you can train it on

```
Input
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1

Target
0 0 
0 1
0 1
1 1
```

and in matlab format `Input = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1]` and `Target = [0 0 0 1; 0 1 1 1]`.

In other words, `Target` matrix stores target values in columns, and examples in rows, so if you want to use $n$ target labels, simply create a matrix with $n$ columns.

Answer (score 1):

A paper worth looking at would be

Peter M. Williams, Using Neural Networks to Model Conditional Multivariate Densities, Neural Computation, Vol. 8, No. 4, Pages 843-854, May 1996
([doi:10.1162/neco.1996.8.4.843](http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/neco.1996.8.4.843))

which provides a method for taking into account the correlations between the output variables, however I rather doubt there will be any neural network package that implements it as standard.